# How to create re-usable library

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a Kotlin library that can be reused across my Android apps.  However I don't want it to be an Android library since I was hoping to hook it up to some testing and mocking frameworks.

In my Android app, I right-clicked on the top-level app node and did `New -> Module` and then selected `Java Library`.  However in the new Java library it seems like Kotlin is only partially being supported. Syntax for the most part works but other things don't.

For instance, `forEach` on my `HashMap` is unresolved as well as attempting to index it such as `items[0]`.  Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to go into module settings and under dependencies (for the reusable library) I added a library dependency on the kotlin-std-lib.  Everything resolves now and seems to be working.